# php exec can't find Java JVM dll although requested path is correct

Tags: java, php, dll, jvm, exec

**I have the following PHP code:**

```
$compileCSS = "C:\ApacheFlexSDK\bin\mxmlc.exe
C:\inetpub\utils\css\\". $_POST['cssFileName'] . ".css" . " 2>&1";
exec ( $compileCSS, $output );
// uncomment to see the response to command
print_r($output);
```

**It runs a command such as:**

```
C:\ApacheFlexSDK\bin\mxmlc.exe
    C:\inetpub\utils\css\sample.css 2>&1
```

**When I run this, I get the following error:**

```
Array ( [0] => Error loading: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_121\bin\client\jvm.dll )
```

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_121\bin\client\jvm.dll` is correct and there is a jvm.dll here.

When I run the command directly from the command line, it works fine, i.e. generate a SWF file (mxmlc is the Apache Flex compiler).

Can't find how to solves this, please help.

Answer (score 0):

You have to wrap either the application with path or the params to the application in double quotes, if they have spaces:

```
$cmd = 'targetapp.exe "C:\my other path with spaces\targetfile.xxx"';
exec($cmd);


$cmd = '"C:\my path with spaces\targetapp.exe" C:\mypathnospaces\targetfile.xxx';
exec($cmd);
```